# Database design for multiple options

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

I have a **Users** table and I'm building an app that keeps track of how many fruits a person eats every day.

When the user enters the app, they select the fruits that they are going to be eating every day. The table would look like this:

```
CurrentlyEating
---------------
ID
FruitID (Foreign Key)
UserID (Foreign Key)
```

There would also need to be a table that contains all the fruits that a user could potentially pick:

```
Fruits
------
ID
Name
```

Is this the best way to achieve this? I've been reading up on lookup tables and I'm not sure if thats a better way to do this. Also, if I decide to add more fruits to this table down the road, I need it to be easy to update in the front-end.

Finally, I have one last table called Journal that records the amount of a specific fruit that the user eats every day:

```
Journal
-------
ID
DateTime
FruitID (Foreign Key)
UserID (Foreign Key)
AmountConsumed
```

So overall, I just want to know if my approach is the optimal way to go about this, and if there are any more efficient approaches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall approach looks pretty good : have a referential table to store all possible fruits, then refer to this using foreign keys. It’s also a good idea to create a separated table to keep user options.

Here is an overall design :

Table USER (you already have it) :

```
id    ...
 1
```

Table FRUITS : all possible fruits (more information can be added like : calories per gram, ...)

```
id    name      ...
 1    orange
 2    banana
```

USER_FRUITS : which user selected which fruit (here, user 1 selected banana)

```
id    user_id    fruit_id
 1             1              2
```

JOURNAL : which user consumed which fruit (user 1 ate 20 grams of banana)

```
id    datetime     user_id    fruit_id    amount
 1         ...                    1              2          20
```

Based on this design, here is a query that returns the journal of a given user :

```
SELECT j.datetime, f.name, j.amount
FROM journal as j 
INNER JOIN fruits as f ON f.fruit_id = j.id
WHERE j.user_id = ?
ORDER BY  j.datetime
```

Comment: And the `FRUITS` table would be the best option if I wanted to update the choices down the road?

Comment: Yes exactly that’s the point of this table, you can easily add new fruits whenever needed

Answer (score 0):

I think your approch is good.And it is optimum way to save this struct of data.